# Как сделать значение ''print(key + ':', info[num][key])'' и нового словаря одинаковыми

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

```
info = {1 : {'name': 'Timur', 'job': 'Teacher'},
        2 : {'name': 'Ruslan', 'job': 'Developer'},
        3 : {'name': 'Rustam', 'job': 'Tester'}}
num = int(input("Какой номер ID? :"))
print('Employee ID:', num)
print()
new_w = {}

for key in info[num]:
    print(key + ':', info[num][key])
print()
for s in info.values():
    new_w.update(**s)
print(new_w)
```

```
Какой номер ID? :1
Employee ID: 1

name: Timur
job: Teacher

{'name': 'Rustam', 'job': 'Tester'}
```

Comment: Если менять номер ID , то новый словарь не меняется. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Кажется, вы вообще не понимаете, что у вас в коде происходит. И вопрос заданный в заголовке у вас в коде решён, а в комментарии у вас вообще другой вопрос. Приведите код и вопрос в порядок. Сейчас вы не понимаете, что делаете в коде и спрашиваете не то, что у вас не получается.

Comment: Я только учусь писать код. Помогите решить проблему пожалуйста

Comment: Когда вы не понимаете, что у вас происходит в коде, вы не можете вопрос правильно. А как тогда такой вопрос решать? Поэтому вашему вопросу пока что можете помочь только вы.

Comment: Я понимаю. Где в коде ошибка? Почему выводится последний вложенный словарь?

Comment: Что проверяется в if num == num:?

Comment: наверное потому, что вы не записываете вложенные словари в словарь, а перетаскиваете ключ-значения из одного словаря в другой. при этом вы каждый раз записываете новое значение в один и тот же ключ

Comment: на будущее - задавайте корректные вопросы. я вот лично ничего не понял, начиная с вашего вопроса, заканчивая тем как ваш код работает и что он вообще должен делать. сядьте, подумайте, сформулируйте задачу, а не вот это вот

Comment: Что проверяется в if num == num:?    Зависимость ввода и ключа 1.2. или3

Comment: Объясните вашу проблему подробнее, что должно выводиться и что выводиться не так?

Comment: при вводе цифр 1 или 2 или 3 должен выводиться соответствующий номер ID это делается . А в конце должен выводиться новый словарь с этими же значениями.

Comment: Неправильно. В if num == num не проверяется абсолютно ничего! Сам озвучь словами что именно там написано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понять ваш вопрос можно лишь выполнив код из вопроса.

А именно:

> при **любом** введенном `num`, в словаре `new_w` оказывается
> только последняя запись из словаря `info`. Почему так происходит?

Если распечатать содержимое словаря `new_w` на каждом шаге цикла - становится более понятно, что происходит:

```
In [134]: for s in info.values():
     ...:     new_w.update(**s)
     ...:     print(new_w)
{'name': 'Timur', 'job': 'Teacher'}
{'name': 'Ruslan', 'job': 'Developer'}
{'name': 'Rustam', 'job': 'Tester'}
```

По причине одинаковых ключей (`name` и `job`) во всех записях исходного словаря, `dict.update()` честно обновляет значения и после последнего шага цикла в них всегда будут значения из последней записи `info`.

В данном ответе я ответил на вопрос "почему так происходит". В вашем вопросе вы нигде не упомянули какой результат вы хотите получить и из вашего кода это тоже непонятно. Поэтому советую вам открыть новый вопрос с примером входных данных и результата, который вы хотите получить **если вам интересно как исправить код**.

PS также настоятельно рекомендую вам ознакомиться с тем:

1. [как правильно задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
2. [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: спасибо большое понял где ошибка